# R Filling vector with predefined values from random position

Tags: r, dplyr

I have column of players and indicator giving me, which one is first. Indicator can randomly at any player. Order is always correct, so result will go from indicator down and then from up until indicator again. Result column is what I'm looking for. There can be different amount of players as well. So in this case, player4 is first one and player3 is last.

How can I fill dynamically result column, with knowledge of indicator spot to it always go correctly?

```
library(dplyr)

x <- c(6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
pos <-  c(NA, NA, NA, "Y", NA, NA, NA, NA)
y <- paste0("player", 1:8)

tibble(player = y,
       pos = pos,
       result = x)
    
# A tibble: 8 x 3
  player  pos   result
  <chr>   <chr>  <dbl>
1 player1 NA         6
2 player2 NA         7
3 player3 NA         8
4 player4 Y          1
5 player5 NA         2
6 player6 NA         3
7 player7 NA         4
8 player8 NA         5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вариант решения

```r
library(tidyverse)
x <- c(6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
pos <-  c(NA, NA, NA, "Y", NA, NA, NA, NA)
y <- paste0("player", 1:8)

df <- tibble(player = y,
       pos = pos,
       result = x)
df %>% 
  mutate(tmp = pos) %>% 
  fill(tmp, .direction = "down") %>% 
  mutate(out = cumsum(!is.na(tmp)),
         out = ifelse(out == 0, row_number() + max(out), out))
#> # A tibble: 8 x 5
#>   player  pos   result tmp     out
#>   <chr>   <chr>  <dbl> <chr> <int>
#> 1 player1 <NA>       6 <NA>      6
#> 2 player2 <NA>       7 <NA>      7
#> 3 player3 <NA>       8 <NA>      8
#> 4 player4 Y          1 Y         1
#> 5 player5 <NA>       2 Y         2
#> 6 player6 <NA>       3 Y         3
#> 7 player7 <NA>       4 Y         4
#> 8 player8 <NA>       5 Y         5
```

or

```
df %>% 
  mutate(tmp = pos) %>% 
  fill(tmp, .direction = "down") %>% 
  mutate(out = ifelse(cumsum(!is.na(tmp)) == 0, row_number() + max(cumsum(!is.na(tmp))), cumsum(!is.na(tmp)))) %>% 
  select(-tmp)
#> # A tibble: 8 x 4
#>   player  pos   result   out
#>   <chr>   <chr>  <dbl> <int>
#> 1 player1 <NA>       6     6
#> 2 player2 <NA>       7     7
#> 3 player3 <NA>       8     8
#> 4 player4 Y          1     1
#> 5 player5 <NA>       2     2
#> 6 player6 <NA>       3     3
#> 7 player7 <NA>       4     4
#> 8 player8 <NA>       5     5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>